# How to adjust the position of the marker(icon) in google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to show the current location to the user. Now I am using icon to denote the location. But the problem is icon is not placed in the exact location. It showing little bit top from the location.[image: map image]

Please refer the screenshot. I want to place the icon in exact blue dot.

I am using following code to show the icon in the map.

```
    latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.navigation_arrow));
    currLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

I don't want to remove the blue dot(GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled). I want to place the icon on that blue dot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove default user's location icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110788/remove-default-users-location-icon)

Comment: I don't want to remove the blue dot. I know how to remove that blue dot. I want to place the icon on exact on blue dot.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16856978/1761003)

Comment: Thanks for the info..!!

Comment: Welcome dude, I guess this is bit difficult to do so as per this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31310683/1761003)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set the anchor point of your `Marker` using the [`anchor` method from the `MarkerOptions`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#anchor(float,%20float)).

By default the anchor point of the `Marker`'s icon is set on the middle bottom.

For example, to set the anchor point on the center of the icon you need to do:

```
markerOptions.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
```

Comment: This what I want..!! :-) :-) :-) ... Thank you @antonio..!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correct location coordinates. And also make sure about the drawable you are using. you can recreate the drawable using this [link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/).